# svn:ignore 'file' is not under version control

Tags: svn

I know that there are a quite a few questions on this out there however none of them make sense so I was hoping that someone could dumb it down for me, cause I am just not getting it.

I have a project (rails) and I want to ignore the SQLite files (among others) from the repository. I have tried adding the files and then ignoring with

```
$ svn propedit svn:ignore "development.sqlite3" db    
svn: 'development.sqlite3' is not under version control

$ svn propedit svn:ignore "*.sqlite3" db    
svn: '*.sqlite3' is not under version control
```

I have tried removing the files and trying the same, and many other combinations and I simply cannot get it to work. I dumped the current build and pulled it down again just to make sure that I was working with a clean copy of the project and no change.

I know that I am missing something, probably something simple, so if someone out there could give me a hand I would appreciate it.

thanks patrick

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but is the folder containing 'development.sqlite3' under source control?

Comment: Yea, the folder is under control, thanks for the idea though. I think that I got it. I removed the files from the repository. I tried $ svn propedit svn:ignore db to just set it for that folder. It brought up an editor where I entered *.sqlite3, and it added the property. I then created the files in the directory and pulled status on the db folder and it showed them as ignored so I think that it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`svn propedit` does not take the filename on the command line.  It lets you edit the property using whatever editor you have configured in your environment.  You want to run

```
svn propedit svn:ignore db
```

which will open your editor, then you can add `development.sqlite3` or `*.sqlite3` or whatever you want to that "file".  It will be changed in your working copy when you exit the editor, and will be updated in the repository the next time you commit the `db` directory.  You can also set the value using the *propset* command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.sqlite3' db
```

But, this only lets you set it the first time, and only to a single filename.  It will overwrite any previous value of svn:ignore.  If you want to ignore multiple files or patterns, you have to use *propedit*, so I just use that all the time.

Comment: +1 for good explanation of difference between propset and propedit.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried?

```
svn delete file_or_dir_name
```

and then commit

Comment: I have and I think that I finally figured it out

Comment: I was not able to ignore files or folders but I finally got the solution.